# Why Text running outside the container even when width is defined to the container

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a parent container inside which one more container is placed. The child container has a text inside P tag. Even though width is defined to the container. below is the HTML lines

```
<div class="textareaPopupWrapper" style="background-color: black;">
  <div class="popupControl">
           <p>This is the text to be display on Popup opens.</p>
  </div>
```

Style for this elements are like below

```
.textareaPopupWrapper {
color: white;
display: block;
height: 100px;
left: 103%;
position: relative;
width: 100px;}

.popupControl {
color: red;
float: left;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
width: 90px;}
```

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?

Comment: I added your code into the Fiddle and it has no issues.  You might have inherited some css somewhere else?  Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c77gR/2/  Try to inspect your code to see if you are inheriting other styles

Comment: so whats your point what are you trying to do

Comment: Sorry. There was one more style clashing the alignment. 
white-space: nowrap; Now this style is removed and its working fine. How can I delete this post from here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close main div. Just check, may be it is causing problem.